# Connect with Soundcloud

Tags: soundcloud

I want to integrate my application with Soundcloud for having the user statistics and so on, I use the client.authorize_url to send the user to approve the app on Soundcloud and I get the proper access_token but I want to know how to correlate between this access_token t the user that clicked on the client.authorize_url in my backend database (I mean I get the access token but how do I know to save it in the DB for the right user?)

Answer (score 0):

Note: not a soundcloud dev.

There are two possible questions being asked here and I'm not sure really what you are asking.

If you are asking about storing data pertaining to a user that has connected through your app: Why do you need to store access tokens on your database? Access tokens expire, and they will change over time, even if it is the same user. It is better to store user-specific data (if needed at all) to a database referencing the users ID. That specific ID will not change. If you are talking about

If you are asking about the app itself, and how to reference that users information once they connect: This is done by using the method call on the SDK (not 100% on the name as I use custom implementations) for Me(). Check the documentation for more info. Hopefully this helps - if you needs some clarification let me know.